# Correct syntax for alias command in Powershell with -p?

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I am using Powershell and 7zip together:

```
$passwd = "password123"
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe" 
sz a -t7z -sfx'7z.sfx' -ppasswordstring $execname $ssftxtname
```

Where the result would have a password of `passwordstring`. How can I replace the last line so it uses `$passwd` variable instead? This:

```
sz a -t7z -sfx'7z.sfx' -p$passwd $execname $ssftxtname
```

Does not seem to give the correct result, as the password entry fails. I assume it's because there's a specific syntax to use?

Comment: Does `$passwd` contain any spaces or punctuation or special characters?

Comment: @briantist No spaces. It may contain numbers or symbols (like #) at times.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the issue is so I don't want to write a full answer at the moment, but I have some ideas. Try using quotes `"-p$passwd"`, or try using a different method to start 7zip, like `Start-Process` where you can explicitly pass in the arguments.

Comment: Hi, 1. adding 7-zip to `PATH` is usually easier 2. Shouldn't it be `sz a -t7z -sfx '7z.sfx' -p $passwd $execname $ssftxtname` with spaces added ? Anyway I'm pretty sure `PATH`can help with parameters.

Comment: @sodawillow According to documentation, no there's no spaces https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/sfx.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use

```
sz a -t7z -sfx'7z.sfx' -p$passwd $execname $ssftxtname
```

you are actually setting the password to the 7-character string comprised of theses characters: `$, p,a,s,s,w,d`.

PowerShell is applying its heuristics to "help" you out, figuring that a dollar sign in the middle of a string is probably *not* a reference to a variable. You can persuade it otherwise simply by quoting the whole argument:

```
sz a -t7z -sfx'7z.sfx' "-p$passwd" $execname $ssftxtname
```

With that, it will set the password to the contents of the `$passwd` variable.

Note that if you have @KeithHill's handy [PSReadLine](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/psreadline-a-better-line-editing-experience-for-the-powershell-console/) module in your startup profile, you will actually see as you type whether you've got a string or a variable. Note the three cases below. The first one is what you tried, but the characters were taken literally. Adding quotes in either the second or third variation shows that `$passwd` is an active variable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add the 7-zip folder to your `PATH` environment variable to make things easier :

```
#find the 7-zip folder path
$7zPath = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files","C:\Program Files (x86)" -Include "7-zip" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).FullName

#add it to PATH environment variable
$env:Path += ";$7zPath;"
```

Then you can run your `7z` commands directly.